# Recursive FizzBuzz function - storing values in a list

Tags: python

I'm dealing with FizzBuzz function. I used recursion:

```
def fizzbuzz_recursive(n):
   if n == 0:
       return
   fizzbuzz_recursive(n - 1)
   if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
       print('FizzBuzz')
   elif n % 3 == 0:
       print('Fizz')
   elif n % 5 == 0:
       print('Buzz')
   else:
       print(n)
```

But I would like to implement list here i.e. when I call my function output should be

```
>>> fizzbuzz_recursive(15)
[1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 7, 8, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 11, 'Fizz', 13, 14, 'FizzBuzz']
```

How to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that instead of printing, it should accumulate the results in a list and return that complete list at the end? What did you try and what is failing?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am pretty much confused with the list. I don't know where should I define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution that accumulates the results is:

```
def fizzbuzz_recursive_list(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    accum = fizzbuzz_recursive_list(n - 1)
    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
        return accum + ['FizzBuzz']
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        return accum + ['Fizz']
    elif n % 5 == 0:
        return accum + ['Buzz']
    else:
        return accum + [n]

print(fizzbuzz_recursive_list(15))
```